# What changed in pathfinder through the years

Tags: pathfinder-1e, history-of-gaming

Pathfinder was released in 2009. Since then it grew with the addition of many books. While adding new stuff is great I won't be surprised if a lot of revision had come along. And since those revision are harder to keep track of, so...

**What are those rules that have changed drastically* trought the years?**
For the purpose of having a clear scope I'm manly interested in the changes on the Core Rulebook, GameMastery guide and Advanced Player's Guide since their respective release date to today, but if you want to expand beyond that is always appreciated.

**I don't need a complete errata list, I prefer the focus on bigger, gameplay impacting, changes*

---

***A bit of Background**: I'm about to join a group which play pathfinder, and while searching for guides (I like to have an idea of how things work at best before I can build my character how I want it) and for edition differences (I come from playing manly 3.5e) I realized that many of the old tips and consideration won't be always valid since the game is still growing, making the whole re-learning harder.*

Comment: Please do not answer in comments.

Comment: FYI, "What rules have changed significantly?" is a very different question to the one recommended, ["What's the difference between Pathfinder then and now?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/94188/#comment217662_94188). Imagine a lumber mill has been rebuilt into an ice skating rink: "how'd the wood get moved around?" is a different question to "what is this building like now compared to before?". If you ask about the difference, we can explain any pertinent rules changes that actually affected gameplay, as well as impact of new published material, the third party landscape, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The core rules have not changed a lot. Only minor erratas, a few nerfs... However there are a bunch of new books, each adding their feats and classes. For example now there are ways to add your DEX instead of your STR to your damage rolls. It makes the encounters against some monsters like goblin rogues a bit scarier.

In particular there is the Unchained book, which suggests many changes in the rules, without making them mandatory. In particular it makes you able to play revised versions of the Monk, the Rogue, the Barbarian and the Summoner, or with alternative rules about many things. Maybe your GM uses these rules, ask him ! Some of these variant rules (like the Unchained Summoner) are enforced during PFS organized plays.